# Create dynamic routes in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm working on ecommerce website, Stuck in nav bar, I have created routes something like this:

```
Route::get('/category/{slug}', 'Site\CategoryController@show')->name('category.show');
```

In slug i pass slug of Product,

but i want to change something like this

```
 Route::get('/{slug}/{slug}', 'Site\CategoryController@show')->name('category.show');
```

i want to remove category prefix and pass main category slug as a first parameter and sub category if it exist as a second parameter otherwise it will be empty.

One more thing i am using TypiCMS, for creating Nestable menu and it is working will i have to modify that also to work with the dynamic route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I don't know anything about your cms framework but in Laravel you cant use the same name for two bindings in your route, they must each be unique.

```php
Route::get('/{categoyrySlug}/{subcategorySlug}', 'Site\CategoryController@show')->name('category.show');
```

And in `Site\CategoryController` you should be able to use :

```php
public function show($categorySlug, $subcategorySlug){
    ...
}
```

and then handle them accodingly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm getting: Missing required parameters for [Route: category.show] [URI: {categorySlug}/{subcategorySlug}] but i have passed second parameter also {{ route('category.show',  $item->slug, $sub_item->slug) }} and sometime when subcategory is not there can i pass NULL as second parameter

Comment: Unless TypiCrm screwed with the default route model binding, it seems like you are missing a slug in one of your variables, I would double check those slugs. But to verify my code works to the view level before the links are actually clicked, you can hard code two known slugs like {{ route('category.show', 'known-slug', 'other-known-slug') }} as I am confident that should work.

Comment: Oh, you're right I always forget to pass them as an array myself, at least we got your there. Congrats!

Comment: One thing more if i want to make second parameter i.e. $subcategorySlug optional i have  passed null to second parameter $subcategorySlug=null but it did'nt find the route

Comment: Add a `?` after the optional parameter like so: `Route::get('/{categoyrySlug}/{subcategorySlug?}', 'Site\CategoryController@show')->name('category.show');`